# group by in sql to find max count

Tags: sql, count

**Update**
I have a query like this

```
select sl.College_ID,sl.Department_ID,COUNT(sl.RegisterNumber)  from StudentList sl
group by  sl.College_ID,sl.Department_ID
order by sl.College_ID,sl.Department_ID asc
```

abouve query gives the below result 
and i have 200 - college id and each college have 6 department_id  i could get the count [No.of student ] in each department

```
College_Id  Dept_Id  count 
1           1           100
1           2           210
2           3           120
2           6           80
3           1           340
```

but my question is i need to display the maximum count[student] for each department

some thing like this

```
college_ID  Dept_Id  count 
3               1       340
26              2       250
```

and i tried this out but getting error

```
select sl.College_ID,sl.Department_ID,COUNT(sl.RegisterNumber)  from StudentList sl
group by  sl.College_ID,sl.Department_ID
having  COUNT(sl.RegisterNumber)=max(COUNT(sl.RegisterNumber))
order by sl.College_ID,sl.Department_ID asc
```

what went wrong can some one help me

Comment: That query should work actually.

Comment: Why is it not working ? Error ? Not excpected result ?

Comment: it shows wrong answer

Comment: I don't understand what the error is ? What do you see on your screen ?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean _"the most-populated department of each college (and the corresponding number of students)"_?

Comment: what is the rdbms? sql server, mysql, oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT sl.College_ID, sl.Department_ID, COUNT(sl.RegisterNumber) As StudentCount, s2.MaxCount
    FROM StudentList sl
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Department_ID, MAX(StudentCount) AS MaxCount
            FROM (
                SELECT College_ID, Department_ID, COUNT(*) As StudentCount
                    FROM StudentList
                    GROUP BY College_ID, Department_ID
                ) s1
            GROUP BY Department_ID
        ) s2 ON sl.Department_ID = s2.Department_ID
    GROUP BY sl.College_ID, sl.Department_ID, s2.MaxCount
    HAVING COUNT(sl.RegisterNumber) = s2.MaxCount
    ORDER BY sl.College_ID, sl.Department_ID ASC
```

**EDIT**: I've updated the query to more accurately answer your question, I missed the part where you want the `College_ID` with the max count.

**EDIT 2**: Okay, this *should* work now, I needed a second nested subquery for aggregating the aggregates. I don't know of a better way to compare the aggregates of different groups.

Comment: no it gives wrong answer . it is giving like entire count but not expected one as mentioned above

Comment: Gah! You're right, sorry. I have to leave for a bit, hopefully someone else can provide a more intelligent answer but if not I'll look further.

Answer (score 0):

The result you want, which is group on **college_ID** and you not really care about **college_ID**, since from you example, with Dept_Id=1 will can not sure which college_ID is.

In that case, you can remove **college_ID** from your select statement and do a `SUM` `GROUP BY`

base on your query, something like:

```
SELECT t.Department_ID, SUM(t.c)
FROM (
select sl.College_ID,sl.Department_ID,COUNT(sl.RegisterNumber) c from StudentList sl
group by  sl.College_ID,sl.Department_ID
) t
GROUP BY t.Department_ID
ORDER BY SUM(t.c)
```

Note: If you really want **college_ID** in your result, you can do a `JOIN` to get your **college_ID**